# Render dynamic count divs in column with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

who can write logic in JavaScript for rendering divs by columns. In every column 4 divs. Divs count is dynamic.

something like this

```
div1 div5 div8
div2 div6 div9
div3 div7 div10
div4 div7 div11 ........
```

i am tried with map and for but i cant.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new row for every fourth element:

```
  const parent = document.body; // or whatever
  let row;
  for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    if(i % 4 === 0) {
      row = document.createElement("div");
      row.className = "row";
      parent.appendChild(row);
   }

   const child = document.createElement("div");
   child.className = "child";
   child.textContent = "div " + i;
   row.appendChild(child);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use css layout if you want to seperate the divs like that, always render the element without sperate the element into something , thats the best practice